# Don't Cross this Riley

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

> My prefix is helpful if reversed,
>   My infix is in the past,
>   My suffix can be a friend
>   Just a little direction you may append.
>   
>   look at me from a different angle
>   and this puzzle you may untangle.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> Diagonally

My prefix is helpful if reversed,

> Aid

My infix is in the past,

> Ago

My suffix can be a friend

> Ally

Just a little direction you may append.

> Needs an N to complete the word

look at me from a different angle

> Descriptive of "diagonally"

and this puzzle you may untangle.

> Seems so.

Comment: you got it right, congrats if you got it by yourself, if you took help from @hexomino 's answer, i would suggest acknowledgment of the clues you needed help with. good job nevertheless .

Comment: D'oh! Well done.

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid No help, I actually thought the exact same initially but paused for thought before answering as I felt the suffix was a little too tenuous. Didn't take long from first reading to get to that point, maybe 2 minutes.

Comment: well done on the answer, btw, do you have any feedback for the riddle?

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid I think it's nice, it works and scans well too.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is

> Diagonal

My prefix is helpful if reversed,

> **Dia** is "aid" reversed.

My infix is in the past,

> **Ago** - meaning in the past.

My suffix can be a friend

> **Al** - *"If you'll be my bodyguard, I can be your long lost pal"*

Just a little direction you may append.

> N for North, the only letter yet to be included.

look at me from a different angle 
and this puzzle you may untangle.

> A diagonal line is set at an agle from horizontal and vertical.

Comment: suffix isn't the intended one, got the rest of the clue correct though.